# Is org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.limit reasonable to use for large values?

Tags: apache-spark

I have ~15GB of data with two columns:  Long and Double.  I want to sort by the Double and pull top-*N* values.  Should be quick and easy with ~92 vCores on 24 nodes, right?

For simplicity, I've factored out task deserialization time.

- When *N* = 10,000, it runs in 1 minute.
- When *N* = 100,000, it runs in 1.5 minutes.
- When *N* = 1,000,000, it runs in 21 minutes.

This is my code:

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/data").toDF()
val n = 1000000
val sorted = df.sort($"_2".desc)
val limited = sorted.limit(n)
val rdd = limited.rdd

import java.io._

val pw1 = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"))
for (line <- rdd.toLocalIterator) { pw1.println(line) }
pw1.close()
```

Comment: If your idea is to save a partition of your `df` you could filter it, and then save it using `spark-csv`

Comment: The heart of the question is less about the saving and more about understanding the operations (and cost!) involved in the `limit`.

Comment: Wait... `limit` returns a DataFrame... I had assumed it _doesn't_ all get shipped back to the driver.  It makes sense that there would need to be a single point of consolidation to preserve the order globally.  I guess that's the question.

Comment: You are totally right, I apologize!